# Average columns between date range from a different table

Tags: sql

so I'm sure there is a simple solution here but I can't get it to work. I currently have two tables structured as so:

```
Table 1                                                                  Table 2
Name    Date    x      y     z                                         Name      Date

John    03/11   91     15    3                                         Mary      05/26
Mary    05/25   95     10    1                                         John      08/15
John    08/14   89     13    5 
John    08/15   85     11    4
```

I want to be able to get the averages for each of the columns (x,y,z) for each person where the date in table 1 is within 7 days prior of the date in table 2. ie it should average the 2nd and 3rd entries for John and the entry for Mary. I have tried:

```
SELECT avg(x), avg(y), avg(z)
FROM table1
Where table1.Date
in(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table1.date BETWEEN table2.date AND table2.date - DATEADD(day, 7, table2.date)
GROUP BY table1.Name = table2.Name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "SQL" is different for each database - please choose a tag that identifies which database you need the solution for5.

Comment: by the way, the order of values used with `between` really do matter. the smaller/lower/earlier value must be first (eg `between 99 and 1` will not work, but `between 1 and 99` does work)

Comment: "I have two tables", but you only show one.  That is a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should give the expected results. I assume it is SQL server so it will work in SQL server

```
SELECT t.name,avg(x), avg(y), avg(z)
FROM table1 t 
Where exists 
(select 1 from  table2 t2 where t2.name = t.name  and t.date between dateadd(day, -7, t2.date) and t2.date )
GROUP BY t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to use an `IN` statement. You want to compare the data in each table but you only need the output from one of the tables. In this case, I would recommend using an `EXISTS` statement. Please note I assume you are using SQL Server.

```
-- utilizing an exists statement because the rows from tbl2 aren't needed for the output, only the comparison with tbl1 data
select      a.Name  Name
            ,avg(X) Avg_X
            ,avg(Y) Avg_Y
            ,avg(Z) Avg_Z
from        tbl1    a
where       exists(select * from tbl2 b where b.Name = a.Name and a.Dt between dateadd(day,-7,b.Dt) and b.Dt)
group by    a.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

select 
t1.Name, t1.Date 
into #temp1 
from t1 join t2 where 
t1.name = t2.name and t1.date >= DATEDADD(day,-7,t2.date) and t1.date <= t2.date 
group by t1.Name, t1.Date

select 
t1. Name, t1.Date, avg(x) as avgX, avg(y) as avg (y), avg(z) as avgZ 
from #temp1 join t1 on #temp1.Date = t1.Date and #temp1.Name = t2.Name 
group by t1. Name, t1.Date